# Why are my Paging controls not showing up on my page at runtime in my ASP.net GridView control?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview, paging

I'm trying to implement an ASP.net GridView control with paging. A lot of descriptions indicate that by setting a couple of quick properties, paging will "just work."

The issue I have is that the paging controls are not displaying at the bottom of my GridView.
I see them in VS Designer.

When I inspect the generated table in the browser debugger, I see that an empty row  has 
been created at the last row in the generated table (presumably this is where the paging controls will be inserted).

**Here is the HTML gridview definition:**

```
<asp:gridview id="gvMasters" runat="server" cssclass="tblMasterDetail" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5"   
AllowSorting="True" visible="True" ClientIDMode="Static" >

<headerstyle cssclass="HeaderStyle" />
<alternatingrowstyle cssclass="AlternatingRowStyle" />
<selectedrowstyle cssclass="SelectedRowStyle" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left"  />

<PagerSettings  Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageText="First Page" LastPageText="Last Page" 
        NextPageText="Next Page" PreviousPageText="Previous Page" PageButtonCount="20" 
        Position="Bottom" Visible="true"/>
</asp:gridview>
```

I'm using a DataTable as my GridView datasource.
**Here is a snapshot of my codebehind:**

```
 gvMasters.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        dvMasters = dtMasters.DefaultView
        Dim strKeys() = {"TxnID"}
        gvMasters.DataKeyNames = strKeys
        gvMasters.DataSource = dvMasters

        ' If return results are empty, we still want to display columns
        If dtMasters.Rows.Count <= 0 Then
            dtMasters.Rows.Add(dtMasters.NewRow())
            isEmpty = True
        End If

        gvMasters.DataBind()

        If isEmpty Then
            gvMasters.Rows(0).Visible = False
            gvMasters.Rows(0).Controls.Clear()
        End If

        gvMasters.Visible = True
```

I have spent several hours trying to figure this out.
What am I doing wrong/missing here?
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your markup uses `id="gvMasters1"` but your code behind uses `gvMasters`. Was that a typo or maybe the problem?

Comment: Could be the pageSize's value grather than dtMasters.Rows.Count? How many rows at dtMasters?

Comment: 1000 rows returned in dtMasters; I changed pageSize to 20. When I look at it in Chrome/Inspect, I can see an empty row where the pager table/controls should be.

Comment: j.f.: - typo, I was trying to clean up sample for posting.

Comment: Figured it out. I was setting a cell's visibility to false instead of using a css style (display:none) to hide the cell containing the key field. Thx for input and looking at this with me. JB